# Chef/Ruby: Bad HTTP response returned from server (401). (WinRM::WinRMHTTPTransportError)Ruby:

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, winrm

**Note: I'm using Active Directory authentication - there's no way around this.**

I'm trying to use the following script:

```
require 'winrm'

IP=ARGV[0]
USER=ARGV[1]
endpoint = "http://#{IP}:5985/wsman"
winrm = WinRM::WinRMWebService.new endpoint, :plaintext, user: USER, pass: 'secret', basic_auth_only: true
winrm.set_timeout 1800

installer_file = "c:\\Users\\#{USER}\\Downloads\\chef_client.msi"
installer_cmd = "msiexec /qn /i #{installer_file} ADDLOCAL=\"ChefServiceFeature,ChefClientFeature\""

puts 'Installating Chef'
puts installer_cmd
install_output = winrm.cmd installer_cmd

sleep 300
puts 'Configuring Chef'
winrm.cmd %Q(mv c:\\Users\\#{USER}\\Downloads\\client.rb c:\\chef\\client.rb)
winrm.cmd %Q(mv c:\\Users\\#{USER}\\Downloads\\chef-validator.pem c:\\chef\\validation.pem)
winrm.cmd 'net start chef-client || net start chef-client'
```

When I do:  `ruby chef_windows_boostrap.rb test168.domain.com ctote`, I get the following output:

```
c:\opscode\chef>ruby chef_windows_boostrap.rb test168.domain.com ctote
Installating Chef
msiexec /qn /i c:\Users\ctote\Downloads\chef_client.msi ADDLOCAL="ChefServiceFeature,ChefClientFeature"
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/winrm-1.1.3/lib/winrm/http/transport.rb:48:in `send_request': Bad HTTP response returned from server (401). (WinRM::WinRMHTTPTransportError)
        from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/winrm-1.1.3/lib/winrm/winrm_service.rb:368:in `send_message'
        from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/winrm-1.1.3/lib/winrm/winrm_service.rb:113:in `open_shell'
        from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/winrm-1.1.3/lib/winrm/winrm_service.rb:239:in `run_cmd'
        from chef_windows_boostrap.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

below is my winrm config settings:

```
c:\opscode\chef>winrm get winrm/config
Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 150
    MaxTimeoutms = 1800000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
        AllowUnencrypted = true
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Digest = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = true
            CredSSP = false
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        TrustedHosts
    Service
        RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GWGX;;;WD)
        MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
        MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 15
        EnumerationTimeoutms = 60000
        MaxConnections = 25
        MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
        AllowUnencrypted = true
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = false
            CredSSP = false
            CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        IPv4Filter = *
        IPv6Filter = *
        EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
        EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
        CertificateThumbprint
    Winrs
        AllowRemoteShellAccess = true [Source="GPO"]
        IdleTimeout = 180000
        MaxConcurrentUsers = 5
        MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
        MaxProcessesPerShell = 15
        MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 300
        MaxShellsPerUser = 5
```

At this point, I'm pretty lost on what to try - anyone have some suggestions? Is there a way I can wireshark this to help debug or something?

Comment: Http Error 401 is "Unauthorized". You may need to provide some other credentials.

Comment: possibly related to some Chef craziness ? https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/KNIFE-22

Answer (score 0):

The following scripts has to be run on the windows server.

```
winrm set winrm/config/client/auth @{Basic="true"}
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}
winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}
```

Source: http://talk.manageiq.org/t/steps-to-join-hyper-v-vmm-to-manageiq/151

Comment: If you run from powershell, you get error:  'Invalid use of command line'. You must run this from 'cmd'